# Why would the S3URL for a submittal attachment be unobtainable if included in the Data Connector Submittal report?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I am iterating through the submittal attachments CSV in a C# solution to download the attachment files associated with a given submittal item. During this, I've reached a snag. On this specific attachment (so far), the S3URL method returns a null value. On further inspection in postman, the following 403 error response is observed.

```
{
    "developerMessage": "ACM check failed, user or calling service does not have access to perform this operation",
    "userMessage": "",
    "errorCode": "AUTH-012",
    "more info": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/documentation/v1/errors/AUTH-012"
}
```

AUTH-012 is not listed as a valid error in the OAuth error handling documentation either. Here are a handful of considerations made during my investigating.

- The permissions for the 3 legged token are sufficient for file download, as the other submittal items download just fine.
- The associated submittal does not appear in the Project Management Submittal list on the BIM 360 site, skipping from #25 to #27
- I am an account administrator for the BIM 360 tenant and have blanket access to all projects and associated files.
- The submittal's status is void, but when other voided submittal attachments are attempted, the S3URL is obtained without issue and the attachment downloads fine.

What could be happening in the background that would prevent this attachment from being downloaded?

Comment: I now understand that the error just points to a "Resource does not exist" error, but this still does not explain why, 1. other voided submittals have downloadable attachments still and 2. the submittal attachment item has a is_deleted value of "f", which makes me believe it would still be available for download.

Answer (score 0):

There are few reasons why Project submittals may not be available for viewing:

- The project member is not assigned the role of Document Manager.
- The submittal status is Open.
- The project member is not assigned as a submittal reviewer.

Kindly, may you try the following and resubmit your request and let us know if the issue persists for further review

- Assign the role of Document Manager to the project member.
- Change the submittal status from Open to Closed.
- Assign the project member as a reviewer of the submittals that they
  need to view.